# Angular 6 - Form - Select Option not updating properly

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-ngmodel

Could someone tell me, why select option not getting updated properly. but console am getting proper value whatever that i changed.

Have form with select option and save button. whenever i change, its show [0][0] - [0][0] in my view. pls the [complete code is here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fx9evb?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

```
form name="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #f="ngForm" novalidate>
    <div class="form-group" contenteditable="false" *ngFor="let val of mockData">
        <p>{{val.description}}</p>
        <label for="sort" class="col-sm-2 control-label"> select current type </label>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <select [(ngModel)]="saveData.selectedValue1" (change)="currChanged()" name="selectedValue1" >
                <option *ngFor='let d of dropDownString' [value]="d.currencyType">
{{d.currencyType}}
</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <label for="sort" class="col-sm-2 control-label"> select max rate </label>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <select [(ngModel)]="saveData.selectedValue2" (change)="rateChanged()" name="selectedValue2" #selectedValue2 = "ngModel">
                <option *ngFor='let c of currencyValue' [value]="c.maxRate">
{{c.maxRate}}
</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button>Save</button>
</form>
```

kindly where am making fault and what have to change.

Note: i just want save select option values separately and should description without any changes from get response. for time being am using some hard coded data.

thanks in advance

Comment: What's the main problem? Are u trying to save data in db?

Comment: yes, trying to save and load saved data back as well.

Comment: i think that's not an issue. am getting value properly in console. my issue. selected value is not populated properly in view.

Comment: @worstCoder, are you calling the service to get the fresh data after you have saved the data ?

Comment: yeah bro.. that implement ion is under roadmap

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `replace` functions you need to replace the placeholders with `this.saveData.selectedValue1` or `this.saveData.selectedValue2`. `this.saveData` is bound to the values of both `select` elements via `ngModel`.

Example:

```
data.description = data.description.replace(this.prevSelectValue1, this.saveData.selectedValue1);
```

You also need to update your previously selected value accordingly:

```
this.prevSelectValue1 = this.saveData.selectedValue1;
```

> Stackblitz
>   [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-d9artq?file=src/app/app.component.ts).

Comment: simply awesome... working great. you got 100/100 starsssssssssssss :)